# Query json_array in where clauses by key and value

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have a select query witch returns me an array_to_json object. I want to filters the results of select based on specifics keys and values.

Here is my actual query:

```
select jsonarray
from (
         SELECT body.id_user,
                array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(body))) as jsonarray
         FROM (
                  SELECT  id_user, name, value
                  FROM table_1
                  group by id_user, name, value
              ) body
         group by body.id_user
     ) as test;
```

It returns a lot of rows like this:

```
[{"id_user": 1489, "name": "name 1", "value": "value aaaaaa"},  {"id_user": 1489, "name": "name 2", "value": "value babababab"}]

[{ "id_user": 1490, "name": "name 12", "value": "value aaaaaa"  }, { "id_user": 1490, "name": "name 2",  "value": "value babababab" }]

[ { "id_user": 1491, "name": "name 13", "value": "value aaaaaa"  }, { "id_user": 1491,  "name": "name 23",  "value": "value uouououo" }]
```

Well, I want only the rows that have the fields "name": "name 2",  "value": "value babababab" into the json... I've tried

```
select jsonarray->'name'
from (
....
     ) as test
where jsonarray->>'name'::text = 'name 2';
```

but it returns nothing. There's another way to query it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to filter it from your innermost subquery? `WHERE name = 'name' AND value ='some_value'`

Comment: yes, there is. It's because I need the entire json and if I use where name = 'name' I don't have the fields with other names, do u understand?

Comment: What's the purpose of the inner `group by`? Why don't you use `distinct`?

Comment: The purpose is for to make a lot of rows return only one json array by user_id. If I don't do the inner group by my query will not return the whole results that I expect...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `name 2` is present during the aggregation:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(body)) as jsonarray
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id_user, name, value
  FROM table_1
) body
group by body.id_user
having bool_or(name = 'name 2') -- those with at least one `name = 'name 2'`
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3de9360cd0df146bec9487b4e4522016)

Comment: Thanks for answer @a_horse_with_no_name but if I do like that, how can I ensure that the lines with 'name 2' also will have the value ""babababab" for this attribute?